# Custom Component with condition in Right bar

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I try to create a component which has the possibility to change the **URL**, **IMAGE-Link** and **DESCRIPTION** in the right bar. For example at the standard component Report I can choose which report should be displayed. How can I add this option for custom components. I googled at lot but I didn't find something about this.

I created a custom template in lightning builder with a lot of fields like a tablet. Now I want to put in to each field the custom component with different content. My actual solution is to add for each field a component.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://mydomain--xxx--c.visualforce.com/resource/1234567891011/image2display?"/>  
        Description
</a> 
    
</aura:component>




({
    doSomething : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Hey There .. the anchor was clicked');
        console.log(event) ;
        var href = event.srcElement.href;
        console.log(href);
        
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aura Component **Design Resources** is the solution to your problem. Official SF documentation can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm). Within your Aura component directory, you need to create a `.design` file and include the component attributes that you want to expose as `design:attribute`. So, your aura component could be as given below:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="url" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="imagelink" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="description" type="String"/>
    
    <a href="{!v.url}" target="_blank">
            <img src="{!v.imagelink}"/>  
            {!v.description}
    </a> 
    
</aura:component>
```

And, the design attributes (in `.design` file) could be defined as shown in the code snippet below:

```
<design:component label="<Component Label>">
    <design:attribute name="url" label="URL" description="Placeholder for the url value"/>
    <design:attribute name="imagelink" label="Image Link" description="Provide the image url here"/>
    <design:attribute name="description" label="Description" description="Brief overview of the link"/>
</design:component>
```

You may specify default values for the design attributes, make it as a picklist, specify form factor support etc. The component attributes of different instances of this component (*in the same or different lightning pages*) would get the value provided via the design attributes (*in the properties pane within Lightning App Builder*).